# Inno Setup function CheckItem syntax and usage

Tags: inno-setup

Following on from my question [Inno Setup disable component selection when a specific component is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026473/inno-setup-disable-component-selection-when-a-specific-component-is-selected), I think there may be a way to get this to work without the problem of checked states set in code being permanent (though use of the `Checked` property) by instead using:

```
function CheckItem(const Index: Integer; const AOperation: TCheckItemOperation): Boolean;
```

in `TNewCheckListBox`, however I am having trouble getting the syntax correct. I am trying:

```
CheckItem(CompIndexSync, coUncheck) := Checked[CompIndexClient];
```

where the `CompIndexes` are constants assigned to the indexes for the component values. I get an Identifier Expected error at compile. Can someone advise how to correctly use this function and what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CheckItem` member of the `TNewCheckListBox` class is a method of type function which updates the checked state by the `AOperation` operation and returns True if any changes were made to the state of the item at `Index`, or any of its children. Here is its prototype ([`source`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_5/Components/NewCheckListBox.pas#L1256)):

```
function TNewCheckListBox.CheckItem(const Index: Integer;
  const AOperation: TCheckItemOperation): Boolean;
```

The problem was that you were trying to assign a value to the function result. That's not what you can do in Pascal language in general.
What you want to do with the item(s) is passed by the `AOperation` parameter. In pseudocode e.g.:

```
var
  CheckList: TNewCheckListBox;
  Operation: TCheckItemOperation;
begin
  ...
  if ShouldCheck then
    Operation := coCheck
  else
    Operation := coUncheck;

  if CheckList.CheckItem(ItemIndex, Operation) then
    MsgBox('An item has changed its state.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. I now have this function working correctly and using it resolves the problem I discovered I was getting through using `Checked[CompIndexSybSync] := False;` in that it was not ever possible to check the components. I have also got the Type Combo Box working to update the components. Still looking to see if I can resolve the refresh / redraw issue and I will be there.