# Inno Setup: TInputOptionWizardPage disabled radio buttons look partially enabled (bug?)

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have a custom page in my Inno Setup script that I create by doing the following:

```pascal
var    
  installSelectPage: TInputOptionWizardPage;
  { ... }

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  installSelectPage :=
    CreateInputOptionPage(wpInfoBefore,
     'Select Destination Location', 'Where should {#MyAppName} be installed?',
     'Please select which {#MyGameName} distribution you want to mod',
     True, False);

  radioIndex_retailInstall := installSelectPage.Add('Retail/DVD');
  radioIndex_steamInstall := installSelectPage.Add('Steam');
  radioIndex_manualInstall := installSelectPage.Add('Manual Directory Selection')
```

Then at some point later in the `InitializeWizard` procedure I read some registry keys and disable the radio buttons who's respective keys aren't found:

```
  if not(retailInstallAvailable) then
    installSelectPage.CheckListBox.ItemEnabled[radioIndex_retailInstall] := False;

  if not(steamInstallAvailable) then
    installSelectPage.CheckListBox.ItemEnabled[radioIndex_steamInstall] := False;
```

This mostly works, but there's some odd error with the appearance of the buttons. While testing this on a machine where both the first and second button are disabled (the third never is), when I first arrive at this custom page if none of the options are select they look like this:

[image: Bugged 'disable style' buttons]

It's subtle, but if you look closely you will notice how the first two radio buttons (not their text) still look partially enabled (and to varying degrees!).

If I then select the third option (only one available on this machine), hit back and then next again to refresh the page the buttons then look correct:

[image: Correct'disable style' buttons]

Does anyone know what the heck Inno Setup is doing and how I can get the buttons to look fully disabled while none of the buttons are selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem.

It seems to happen when the focused item is disabled. The focused item is by default the first one. Make sure you set `ItemIndex` to the index of an (first) enabled item.

```
installSelectPage.CheckListBox.ItemIndex := ...;
```

Comment: I originally figured it had something to do with a focus issue, but since when you get to this page the next button is highlighted and clearly has the overall focus of the program (hitting tab moves along the back, next, and cancel buttons) I didn't prod further. I did not realize that the CheckListBox itself had a member that tracked focus for its own options. Changing the focus to any radio button of my choosing that was not disabled did indeed fix the problem. It is also worth noting that the underlying issue may be related to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31167028